# How to avoid duplicating the HTML text because mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, angular

Here is the sample code for the website,

```
<div class="web">
<br>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li role="presentation"><a [routerLink]="['/home', {outlets: {router2: 'newsfeed'}}]">News Feed</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a [routerLink]="['/home', {outlets: {router2: 'photos'}}]">Photos</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="mobile">
<br>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation"><a [routerLink]="['/home', {outlets: {router2: 'newsfeed'}}]">News Feed</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a [routerLink]="['/home', {outlets: {router2: 'photos'}}]">Photos</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

.web
{
    padding-top: 10%; 
    position: fixed;
}

.mobile
{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
}


 @media only screen and (max-device-width:480px){
       /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
       .web
       {
           display: none;
       }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
       /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
       .mobile
       {
           display: none;
       }
    }
```

I would like to know how can i avoid doing this?

I have different styles for mobile and web but the inner content is same, how can avoid duplicating my html just because of responsiveness.

PS: Its an angular2 website!

Comment: Do you understand how the `@media` query works?

Comment: I have just started using it. Kind of understand the logic.

Comment: This is so cute! You were so close haha! So the way this works is you need to remove the duplicate HTML. Next, within both of the @media queries add the same class of `web` and apply different styles to them. That's how it's designed to work!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeating yourself, use @media quires to override the first style. You could do this by:

- putting !important at the end of the styles: e.g. `position: fixed !important` (not recommended)
- making your style specified. e.g. `html .div` instead of `div`
- putting you @media code after the initial code
- putting your style sheet before the initial stylesheet in the `<head></head>`(Can't remember if it was before or after)

I override the styles by putting the @media code **after** the initial code:

```css
.web {
  padding-top: 10%;
  position: fixed;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) {
  /* styles for mobile browsers larger than 480px; (iPhone) */
  .web > ul {
    /* insert .nav-stacked code here */
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
  .mobile {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="web mobile">
  <br>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li role="presentation"><a [routerLink]="['/home', {outlets: {router2: 'newsfeed'}}]">News Feed</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a [routerLink]="['/home', {outlets: {router2: 'photos'}}]">Photos</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Update**: That's the way to do it entirely using CSS. If you are willing to use JS, then there are more elegant ways of doing it.

Comment: you haven't noticed, that i am using two different classes on it. one i have using nav-stacked and other i am not.